# How to replace C standard library function ?

Tags: c

How can we replace a C standard library function with our own implementation of that function ?

For example, how can I replace `strcpy()` with my own implementation of `strcpy()` and have all calls link to the new implementations instead?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What could *possibly* be the point?

Comment: Is it really worth the trouble?  You would have to edit the string.h header file, whose location depends on the system and environment you are using.  But I think you would be better off writing a separate function.

Comment: @CodyGray, I guess, looking at FatalError's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107259/how-to-replace-c-standard-library-functioin#9107319), that you could replace every call in an executable to your own which prints debugging? Or something like that, I guess. Probably not good practice though. You should write a new function with a different name and change all calls.

Comment: as @CodyGray has said, you shouldn't try to override standard library functions that have been proven to be accurate and are optimized to perfection.

Comment: @IntermediateHacker How about standard library functions that are buggy? [Some](http://sources.redhat.com/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=10089) [bug](http://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=3326) [reports](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/+bug/270694) concerning `rintf()`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

At least with GCC and glibc, the symbols for the standard C functions are *weak* and thus you can override them. For example,

strcpy.c:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char * strcpy(char *dst, const char *src)
{
  char *d = dst;
  while (*src) {
    *d = *src;
    d++;
    src++;
  }
  printf("Called my strcpy()\n");

  return (dst);
}

int main(void)
{
  char foo[10];
  strcpy(foo, "hello");

  puts(foo);

  return 0;
}
```

And build it like this:

```
gcc -fno-builtin -o strcpy strcpy.c
```

and then:

```
$ ./strcpy 
Called my strcpy()
hello
```

Note the importance of `-fno-builtin` here. If you don't use this, GCC will replace the `strcpy()` call to a builtin function, of which GCC has a number.

I'm not sure if this works with other compilers/platforms.

Comment: Fun fact, my `strcpy()` above has a pretty serious flaw. Since it's not really the focuse here, I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader ;).

Comment: That's sort of the point, though. Replacing the tried-and-true library functions with one of your own is almost 100% guaranteed to have serious flaws.

Comment: As for the flaw: in this version of `strcpy()`, the loop condition will never be false if `src` and `dst` are overlapping.

Comment: I don't think `strcpy()` was *ever* guaranteed against overlapping strings. However, it *is* guaranteed to nul-terminate dst ;).

Answer (score 7):

You can try playing with [LD_PRELOAD](http://lca2009.linux.org.au/slides/172.pdf) if you are on Linux.

Comment: This seems to be the right way. [Here](https://github.com/nibrahim/Random-hacks/tree/master/malloc-trace) is an example but the real question is why?

Comment: This is called interposing a library.  You have to create a C module that is compiled as PIC (position independent code) into a .so file.    Then you set LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/mystrcpy.so  You can also accomplish the same thing by calling dl_open() in your code. It is easier simply to create mystrcpy.c compile that into an object module and call that everywhere else in your code, and link to the mystrcpy object module.  You will have to use an extern declaration for mystrcpy everywhere as well.  see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426230/what-is-the-ld-preload-trick

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure how hard it will be to get the linker to do what you want, but here's a solution that doesn't involve changing any linker settings and uses preprocessor macros instead so that any code that tries to call strcpy actually calls a function called my_strcpy:

**mystuff.h:**

```
#define strcpy my_strcpy
char * my_strcpy(char * dst, const char * src);
```

**my_strcpy.c:**

```
#include <mystuff.h>
char * my_strcpy(char * dst, const char * src);
{
    ...
}
```

**my_code.c:**

```
#include <mystuff.h>

int main()
{
   /* Any call to strcpy will look like a normal call to strcpy
      but will actually call my_strcpy. */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the `--wrap` linker flag: `-Wl,--wrap=strcpy`

Then you can define your replacement as `__wrap_strcpy`. If you need the original function it is renamed to `__real_strcpy`:

```
extern char *__real_strcpy(char *dest, const char *src);

char *__wrap_strcpy(char *dest, const char *src) {
    ...
}
```

This works great if you only need to replace a few functions, but if you wanted to replace lots of functions it could get unwieldy to specify them all in the linker flags.