# How write a replacement function for a standard C library function

Tags: c

I have a school assignment that is calling for the replacement of the standard memory allocation functions within the standard library of C. I am not sure how to do this but here is the brief description my teacher is using to outline his process.

> Next, I'm going to #define the standard C memory allocation and free
>   functions to be replaced by their memcheck counterparts.  In each
>   case, I'm looking up the number and names of the arguments in the man
>   page and using them in both the original function and its
>   redefinition.  In addition, to the arguments that are listed in the
>   man page, I am also passing `(underscore, underscore)FILE(underscore, underscore) and LINE(underscore, underscore)` to the replacement
>   versions as the last two arguments of each function.  I am being
>   careful not to include a semi-colon on either of the two functions in
>   the #define statement.

right now I am just working on the header file:

```
#ifndef MEMCHECK_H
#define MEMCHECK_H

#include<stdlib.h>

#define malloc _memcheck_malloc
#define free _memcheck_free

#endif
```

The point of this project is to replace the standard malloc and free functions with one that is our own and that is being utilised within a linked list.

ultimately what i am asking for is "How do i begin defining my own function that will replace a standard function?" I need to used the #define method as well as a few compiler marcos stated above.

Here is a link to another question that i have found that appears to be the right answer but i am not sure. 
[How to replace C standard library function ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107259/how-to-replace-c-standard-library-function) (3rd answer).

Comment: If you think it holds the answer - why bother to write another Q for that? If you do not think, explain why not.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I have no idea if this answer is correct, and a straight forward answer has been hard to find on google. I am not sure if it is correct solely because i do not entirely understand how #define can be used to replace standard functions.

Comment: The `#define` doesn't change the library, but modifies any *calls* to the standard function into calling your function instead. The preprocessor replaces `free(ptr)` with `_memcheck_free(ptr)` and the compiler doesn't even know it did that.

Comment: @BoPersson So by the first argument of #define being "malloc" and the second argument being "The name of the function i am replacing malloc with" every time malloc is being called, it will used my replacement function? so I all I need to do now is declare a prototype for the replacement function within my header file and then create a function file that hold the definition of my replacement file. is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `__FILE__` macro expands to a `const char*` containing the name of the current source file. The `__LINE__` macro expands to an `int` that is the line number in the current file where the macro is located. So, the declaration of your new function would have to look like this:

```
void *_memcheck_malloc(size_t size, const char *file, int line);
```

When you define a macro to change all calls to `malloc` to instead call `_memcheck_malloc`, you have to define the additional parameters that the macro will automatically supply to the different function, because any existing call to `malloc` won't include them. You want this

```
32    int *p = malloc(4 * sizeof(int));
```

to be changed into this:

```
32    int *p = _memcheck_malloc(4 * sizeof(int), "filename.c", 32);
```

So, your macro definition looks like this:

```
#define malloc(X) _memcheck_malloc((X), __FILE__, __LINE__)
```

The `X` argument is replaced with whatever exists in the original text; this is simple pattern-matching, so everything within the parentheses in the original text is replaced with everything within the parentheses in the macro invocation. The parentheses around the `X` argument (in the replacement text) are to make sure that whatever expression is supplied to the macro is evaluated as a *single value*.

The `free()`, `calloc()`, and `realloc()` macros would follow this pattern.

**CAVEAT** Macros can be just as tricky as hell, and in the main, should be avoided if possible. This situation is one of the few *widely accepted* uses of macro substitution. Don't be sucked into the idea that "Wow, macros are cool -- I can do all kinds of things with this!" You can, and if you do, you will almost invariably come to regret it.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for, This will be very helpful!