# C function shadowing: why does this example not work?

Tags: c, linker

By experimenting with this simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

double sin (double i){
    printf("Yes!\n");
    return 0.;
}

int main() {
    printf("Do I run my version of sin()?: %lf\n", sin(1));
    return 0;
}
```

I expected to find the function sin "shadowed" by my version, as for instance described in this thread ([Overriding C library functions, calling original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19023018/overriding-c-library-functions-calling-original)).

Surprisingly (to my viewpoint), when I compiled, `gcc example.c`, (same effects with `gcc example.c -lm`) I just obtained the mathematical value of sin. May I ask the reason of that? What should I change to use my definition?

This question aims to a better understanding of the language; I am not trying to solve any specific practical problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace C standard library function ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107259/how-to-replace-c-standard-library-function) Your program will do as you expect if compiled with the `-fno-builtin` flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sin` is a C standard library function that compilers may substitute with a built-in function.

With gcc it is `__builtin_sin`. Compile with `-fno-builtin-sin` to be able to provide your own definition of `sin`.